# How to encrypt or obfuscate strings inside NSURL?

Tags: objective-c

I have a path to a URL, in objective C code

I want to obfuscate or encrypt this value so that users won't see this code

They are integrating my entire code into their apps, but I don't want them to see the url.

What's a way for me to obfuscate the url?

Comment: As the others have said, in more words, no.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have control of the web server, your URLs can be as meaningless or meaningful as you want.  They can be anything and you can map them anyway you want.  Munge bits. Use encryption.  Whatever you want.

The first question to ask is what are you trying to achieve?  Protection from casual hacking or full on security?

Hopefully the former.   If the latter, then you need to hire a security expert.

If the former, then:

• use https and verify the server certificate(s)
• use public key encryption and have your app grab the public key and then encrypt the URL contents
• obfuscate your arguments and values, etc...

... etc ...

Some combination of the above would get you pretty far from keeping casual prying eyes out of your URL space.   If your goal is to keep people out of your server, think about employing a time limited UUID or something that is tagged to the session, generated by the server and cannot be generated on the client.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that since you need the plain url to be translated to a ip address by a nameserver, more than that, once you have the url obfuscated you will won't have anything that can be translated by all servers envolved.

The best way to obfuscate data in a url is by obfuscating only parameters values.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need the URL to send HTTP requests to a server. So every user that has a WLAN with a firewall capable of logging all requests will be able to log and see your URL.

Whatever encryption or obfuscation method you use, it will not have the intended effect. Logging on the firewall is probably even easier than disassembling the app even if the URL is not obfuscated at all.